# Changing the sample frequency of the BMM150 magnetometer on the Nano 33 BLE Sense Rev2

Tags: magnetometer, sample-rate, imu, arduino-nano

I am working with inertial data using the Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense Rev2 board. I have used various libraries, and the one that enables me to access the data effectively is 'Arduino_BMI270_BMM150.h' by Arduino. However, I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to change the sampling frequency of the magnetometer.

Below are a few lines of code from 'Arduino_BMI270_BMM150/src/utilities/BMM150-Sensor-API' that I have modified.

line 808
from
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_10HZ;
to
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_30HZ;

line 818
from
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_10HZ;
to
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_30HZ;

line 828
from
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_10HZ;
to
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_30HZ;

line 838
from
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_10HZ;
to
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_30HZ;

line 1338
from
reg_data = BMM150_SET_BITS(reg_data, BMM150_ODR, settings->data_rate);
to
reg_data = BMM150_SET_BITS(reg_data, BMM150_ODR, BMM150_DATA_RATE_30HZ);

line 1471
from
settings->data_rate = BMM150_GET_BITS(reg_data[1], BMM150_ODR);
to
settings->data_rate = BMM150_DATA_RATE_30HZ;

When I use 'Serial.print(IMU.magneticFieldSampleRate())', I get as output '30', but the serial plotter still provides the standard rate of 10 values per second.

Any suggestions are truly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.